# Getting a decomposition of an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Firstly, I need to admit that my English is quite poor.
Ok. I've got a problem- how can I get any possible decompositions of a given integer? Sample decomposition:

$$\begin{align}
30&=1^2+2^2+5^2=1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2\\
29&=2^2+5^2=2^2+3^2+4^2\\
8&=8
\end{align}$$

All the powered integers can be used only once. Of course, there are some integers that cannot be decomposed like this (for example $8$).

Comment: Maybe these help:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple , 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Comment: "Michael O. Rabin and Jeffrey Shallit have found randomized polynomial-time algorithms for computing a single representation n=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2 for a given integer n." Does anyone know, where can I find this algorithm? I guess it'd make a great progress in my work :) .

Comment: @GDumphart Sorry, I'm really absentminded. I went to the ond of [this article](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1108/1108.6246.pdf) and found only "There is a randomized algorithm for expressing a number N as a sum of four squares which 
requires an expected number of O(log2
(N)loglog(N)) operations with integers smaller than N for all N ≥ N0. ". But where is the exact algorithm?